# How to run Magento 2.3 on several domain aliases, but using only one website (and one storeview)

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I need to create many different magento 2.3 shops as subdomains of the main shop;
eg shop1.domain.com, shop2.domain.com, shop3.domain.com, shop3.domain.com

All those subshops will share the exact same content, products and storeviews (content in different languages using subdirectories /en /fr /de etc) of the main domain and my goal is to not create a different magento website or magento storeview for each of such subdomains.
I'll customize just some graphic of the subdomains by loading a different theme/css based on the HTTP HOST env variable.

Can you tell me how to achieve this?

I've now configures nginx so that all the subdomains are mapped to the same document root, but when now I load a.domain.com I get automatically redirected to [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution: I had just to change the "Auto-redirect to Base URL" to "no" and it worked. Now I've to customize Base URLs, but at least I fixed the automatic redirect

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution to this problem. Are you satisfied with the solution you found? Did it work out in the long run?